# Are there companies that take into account smoking behaviour in their recruitment?

Tags: teamwork, working-conditions

Even though some progress has been done with 'smoke-free' workplaces, in my experience co-workers - who smoke - keep the (toxic) smell with them, clothes and mostly breath, and also take their pauses regularly.

So the question is: are there visible or invisible measures taken by companies to select their employees on this smoking criteria? I guess it's currently illegal to discriminate on this criteria

Are there alternatively any measure to help smokers to stop?

Comment: yes a few oppressive places of employment threaten to garnish the wages of people who freely choose to do so as they wish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more a rant than a question.

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think a good percentage of workers have experienced this 'discomfort' or problem with smokers

Comment: @PhilipKendall reworded the question to sound less as a rant

Comment: People going out to smoke, if allowed by the company, is not your concern. And people smelling bad... well, there is not only smoking there, and the smell has not shown to be bad for your health. And no, I am not (never been) a smoker and I have no issue being near a smoker (as long s/he is not actively smoking).

Comment: Companies select employees to get the work done, not on whether they smoke for a few minutes per day. I don't smoke but taking short breaks is good for productivity - if you take a break to go out and smoke for a few minutes, then this break will have the same good effect on productivity. Of course smoking is not /required/ for a break, but the fact that you do so is not a problem for others unless they do it inside the workplace.

Comment: @SJuan76 "the smell has not shown to be bad for your health" hmm.. I'm talking of situations like talking closely to a smoker, or in the elevator, it's very hard to not notice their exhaled second-hand smoke. Whether it's harmful or not, I don't really know, but seeing the damages done on a smoker (like increased heart-rate, breath-rate, decreased lungs capacity, ...) in my mind, those toxins are still harmful even in lower concentration, and when you smell them it means their concentration is already quite high

Comment: As of a year ago, 21 states did allow employers to ban smokers:  http://jobs.aol.com/articles/2014/04/15/employer-discrimination-against-smokers/

Comment: @n11 It's called “third-hand smoke”. It's a topic of research so I would not say that your concerns are totally unfounded but common sense about smell and toxins is not a very good way to approach the issue. In particular, the assumption that what smells is toxic or that perceiving the smell of cigarette is direct evidence of toxic concentration levels are not warranted. Those things are mostly unrelated, some of the most toxic compounds in cigarette smoke are even odourless to some or most people.

Answer (score 3):

Some companies in the United States have tried to use some incentives. They have paid for programs to help their employees to stop smoking. They have offered lower rates for life and health insurance for non-smokers.

In a few cases they have wanted tougher rules, but they are difficult to enforce. And you can imagine they are not popular.

I am not sure how the availability of e-cigs will change the situation.